# How to change the location of neo4j messages.log file

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to configure the location of messages.log file for the embedded webserver in neo4j 1.9.7

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can configure it, it will be in the same directory as the DB. However, you can specify remote logging via Logback, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.7/kernel-configuration.html